# Register Activity with camera button saving to external database

Tags: java, php, android, database, camera

I am new to Android development. I have a register activity that saves the user input to external database using a PHP script and that works fine.

I decided to add taking a photo of the user and save that as well to the external database so that it gets all the user info and picture taken with the camera button to database. I want to get the info, take a picture, come back to the activity then save everything to the database.

JAVA:

```
public class RegisterActivity extends Activity {

    EditText firstname, email, lastname, age;
    Button signup;
    Spinner country;


    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //set strict mode policy
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);
        //changing font for tittle
        TextView textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextViewTitle);
        Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf");
        textview.setTypeface(font);

        //changing font for firstname and setting Editfirstname from activity
        firstname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditFirstName);
        Typeface font1 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/OpenSans-Light.ttf");
        firstname.setTypeface(font1);

        //changing font for email and setting Editemail from activity
        email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditEmail);
        Typeface font2 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/OpenSans-Light.ttf");
        email.setTypeface(font2);

        //changing font for lastname and setting Editlastname from activity
        lastname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditLastName);
        Typeface font3 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/OpenSans-Light.ttf");
        lastname.setTypeface(font3);

        //changing font for age and setting Editage from activity
        age = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editAge);
        Typeface font4 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/OpenSans-Light.ttf");
        age.setTypeface(font4);


        country = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.SpinnerSelectCountrty);




        TextView textview7 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.CheckBoxResponse);
        Typeface font6 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/OpenSans-Light.ttf");
        textview7.setTypeface(font6);

        TextView textview8 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.CheckBoxResponse1);
        Typeface font7 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/OpenSans-Light.ttf");
        textview8.setTypeface(font7);

        //setup button activity
        signup = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ButtonSignUp);
        //setup onclick listener



        signup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            InputStream is = null;
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                //storing values inside edittexts inside the string variables
                String FirstName = ""+firstname.getText().toString();
                String LastName = ""+lastname.getText().toString();
                String Email = ""+email.getText().toString();
                String Country = country.getSelectedItem().toString().trim();
                String Age = ""+age.getText().toString();


                //setting the name value pair
                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
                //adding the strings variables inside StringValuePairs
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("FirstName", FirstName));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("LastName", LastName));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Email", Email));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Country", Country));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Age", Age));

                //setting up connection inside the try block
                try {
                    //setting up the default http client
                    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    //setting up the http post method and passing  the url for database and php file
                    //that servers as the link between the android app and database server
                    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://myhost.com/demo.php");
                    //passing the nameValuePairs into the httpPost
                    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                    //get response
                    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                    //setting up entity
                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                    //setting up content inside an input stream reader
                    //lets setup the inputreader
                    is = entity.getContent();
                    //Displaying a toast message if the data is entered successfully
                    String msg = "Data entered successfully";
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }   //writing catch to handle the exceptions
                catch (ClientProtocolException e)
                {
                    Log.e("ClientProtocol", "Log_tag");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }catch(IOException e)
                {
                    Log.e("Log_tag", "IOException");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }



            }
        });


    }



}
```

MY XML:

```
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:scrollbars="vertical">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <!--Put form controls here-->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextViewTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/text_color3"
            android:text="@string/feedbacktitle"
            android:textSize="20sp">
        </TextView>
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/EditFirstName"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Enter First Name"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:textColor="@color/text_color2"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp">
        </EditText>
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/EditLastName"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/text_color2"
            android:hint="Enter Last Name"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent">
        </EditText>
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/EditEmail"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/feedbackemail"
            android:textColor="@color/text_color2"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:textSize="10sp">
        </EditText>

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Age"
            android:textColor="@color/text_color2"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/editAge" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/text_color2"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="Please select a team"
            android:id="@+id/textSelectCountry"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp" />



            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/SpinnerSelectCountrty"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:prompt="@string/feedbacktype"
                android:textColor="@color/text_color2"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:entries="@array/feedbacktypelist"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp">
            </Spinner>


        <CheckBox
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Please check box to electronically agree to the tournaments terms"
            android:id="@+id/CheckBoxResponse1"
            android:textColor="@color/text_color2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/CheckBoxResponse"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/text_color2"
            android:text="@string/feedbackresponse"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp">
        </CheckBox>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/ButtonPhoto"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Take a photo"
            android:onClick="sendFeedback"
            android:textColor="@color/text_color2"
            android:layout_below="@id/CheckBoxResponse"
            android:layout_width="152dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp">
        </Button>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/ButtonSignUp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/feedbackbutton"
            android:layout_below="@id/ButtonPhoto"
            android:textColor="@color/text_color2"
            android:onClick="sendFeedback"
            android:layout_width="152dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp">
        </Button>

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

PHP:

```
<?php

$con=mysql_connect('something.com','username','password');
    mysql_select_db("dbname", $con);

    $FirstName=$_POST['FirstName'];
    $LastName=$_POST['LastName'];
    $Email=$_POST['Email'];
    $Country=$_POST['Country'];
    $Age=$_POST['Age'];

    mysql_query("insert into Player_info(FirstName, LastName, Email, Country, Age)        values('{$FirstName}','{$LastName}','{$Email}','{$Country}','{$Age}')");
mysql_close();
?>
```

Comment: Your PHP has serious SQL injection issues, and may be damaged by malicious users, especially if your service becomes popular. You are also using a deprecated library. That file is best written again, using MySQLi or PDO/mysql.

Comment: ok i can redo that part @halfer. How can you help with the camera part? Thanks for the response.

Comment: Not an Android dev, sorry. I can't see if you have actually made a start though - can you give this a go first? The Android docs _must_ detail how to use the camera, as it is a popular feature of the platform.